# Date comparision using Criteria Builder API in java

Tags: java, date, datetime, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I want to compare the current date of the logged in user (according to his timezone) with the table column using criteria API.

But I am not able to get a expression out of the local date I have calculated for the user. How can I resolve this?

```
public void checkTaskCategory(TaskCriteria criteria, CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery<Task> q, Root<Task> task, List<Predicate> predicates) {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(criteria.getCategory())) {
     LocalDate currentDateForUserTimezone = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pago_Pago")).toLocalDate();
        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(TaskConstants.TASK_OVERDUE, criteria.getCategory())) {
            predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(cb.currentDate(), task.<Date>get(TaskConstants.DUE_DATE)));
            predicates.add(cb.notEqual(task.get("status"), getStatus(Status.Value.DONE.toString()).getId()));
            q.orderBy(cb.asc(task.get(TaskConstants.DUE_DATE)));
        }
    }
}
```

I want to replace `cb.currentDate()` with my calculated `currentDateForUserTimezone`  for comparison since `cb.currentDate` doesn't take into account the timezone. How can I achieve it?

Comment: @lonut do you know ?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you could use `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pago_Pago"))`. It's equivalent to (but shorter than) `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pago_Pago")).toLocalDate()`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got the solution. We need to use ParameterExpression in order to compare the column values present in the database with a new user defined object value.And then use the same alias in setParameter to use that value.The code will change something like this :

```
public void checkTaskCategory(TaskCriteria criteria, CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery<Task> q, Root<Task> task, List<Predicate> predicates) {
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(criteria.getCategory())) {
   LocalDate currentDateForUserTimezone =  LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Pago_Pago"));
   ParameterExpression<LocalDate> currentDate = cb.parameter(LocalDate.class, "currentDate");
   if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(TaskConstants.TASK_OVERDUE, criteria.getCategory())) {
        predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(currentDate, task.<LocalDate>get(TaskConstants.DUE_DATE)));
        predicates.add(cb.notEqual(task.get("status"), getStatus(Status.Value.DONE.toString()).getId()));
        q.orderBy(cb.asc(task.get(TaskConstants.DUE_DATE)));
   }
}
```

And then use the alias "currentDate" in setParameter and set the value currentDateForUserTimezone  there, which will compare with the desired field value.
}